# Javascript setInterval() executing twice at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having a problem where I have a single `setInterval()` but it's executing twice at the same time. 
My code clones a image from one div and places it in another one. The `setInterval()` is cloning 3 times the image but in reality it clones 6 times.
I have an alert when the `setInterval` ends. The alert pops out when the 5th clone is placed and again with the 6th clone, which means that the 5th clone is the end of the first `setInterval()` and the 6th is the end of the second one. But I want only 1 `setInterval()` that makes 3 clones. What is happening?

HTML:

```
<div class="inimigo">
     <img src="inimigo.png">
</div>

<div class="jogo2">

</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var counter2 = 0;
    var i = setInterval(function() {
        var inimigo = $(".inimigo").clone();
        $('.jogo2').html(inimigo);

        counter2++;
        if(counter2 === 3){
            alert("end");
            clearInterval(i);
            counter2 = 0;
        }
    }, 200);
});
```

Comment: jquery doesn't have a `setInterval` function - plain ol' javascript does

Comment: @JaromandaX but still can use

Comment: your code as is will add 3 duplicates - the setInterval only get's started once - see [this fiddle of your code](https://jsfiddle.net/98pyntmq/)

Comment: @DonaldWu - yes, but it's not a problem with "jquery setInterval" as stated, as there is no such animal

Comment: @JaromandaX but if it's only started once why it's making 6 clones? And why the alert pops up 2 times? There is something that may be making the setInterval executing 2 times?

Comment: I'm just pointing out that the **code you posted** does not behave the way you claim - something else is going on in code that you perhaps haven't shared

Comment: I edited the code to be a little more readable (horizontal whitespace helps).

Comment: Strange, in the fiddle it clones only 3 times. Hmmm. Something is wrong or with the browser or with the software. Thanks, I will try other browsers or softwares and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess Clone is causing issue.
When you use `html()` you should pass HTML as text.

Please check solution, ( [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jjo7fs59/2/) )

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var counter2 = 0;
    var i = setInterval(function() {
        var inimigo = $(".inimigo").clone();

        // Followin is the fix code
        $('.jogo2').prepend(inimigo.html());
                // or use append to put new content at last
        //$('.jogo2').append(inimigo.html());

        counter2++;
        if(counter2 === 3){
            alert("end");
            clearInterval(i);
            counter2 = 0;
        }
    }, 200);
});
```